# Batch file - read two lines into two separate variable within one for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file (list.txt) which is a list filenames that can be simplified as below:
a
b
c
d

I need a "for" loop that does something like below:

```
set variable1=a  
set variable2=b
do something with variable1 & 2, lets say variable1 + variable2>>output.txt

then restart the loop from the second line:
set variable1=b
set variable2=c
perform the addition>>output.txt

then from the third line:
set variable1=c
set variable2=d etc..
and keep going until the end of my list.txt
```

It seems batch file has difficulty when handling multiple lines of data within a loop.
Could someone kindly shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you written a code or a batch that does this already, but does not work as it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "var1="
SET "var2="
FOR /f %%a IN (q26028954.txt) DO (
 CALL SET "var1=%%var2%%"
 SET "var2=%%a"
 IF DEFINED var1 (
  SET /a total=var1+var2
  CALL ECHO %%var1%% + %%var2%% = %%total%%
  )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Where `q26028954.txt` contains

```
1
4
7
11
```

Yields

```
1 + 4 = 5
4 + 7 = 11
7 + 11 = 18
```

could also be used with `delayedexpansion`. Note the use of the `set /a total` - the run-time, not the parse-time values are applied to the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "file_to_process=c:\some.txt"
set "line="
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%file_to_process%") do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!line!" NEQ "" (
        echo do something with !line! and %%#
    )
    endlocal & set "line=%%#"

)

endlocal
```

Change the path to your file.

Comment: Thank you too npocmaka. I don't quite understand your method as I don't see the two variables. Will give it another go when I got chance. :)

Comment: @Alan - Do you mean it does not work? Because it works for me (and should be pretty fast too as it does not use subroutines)